# Ref is not applied to react sound

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On pageload I get the errors:
Failed prop type: The prop `url` is marked as required in `Sound`, but its value is `undefined`
Failed prop type: The prop `playStatus` is marked as required in `Sound`, but its value is `undefined`
Basically all the properties of the ref named "sound" are not applied to the soundobject.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Sound from 'react-sound'

function AudioButton(props) {
  
  let buttonText = props.state ?  'Turn audio off' : 'Turn audio on'
  
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick}
      className='absolute bottom-0 right-0 z-10 flex items-center justify-center p-3 m-3 text-white transition-colors ease-in-out bg-blue-600 rounded-md cursor-pointer duration-350 hover:bg-blue-800'
    >
      {buttonText}
    </button>
  )
}

function AmbientSound(props) {
  const sound = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    sound.current.url='/sounds/ambientStereoSound.wav'
    sound.current.autoLoad=true
    sound.current.loop=true
    sound.current.volume=100
  }, [])
  if(props.state){
    useEffect(() => {
      sound.current.playStatus=Sound.status.PLAYING
    })
  }else{
    useEffect(() => {
      sound.current.playStatus=Sound.status.PAUSED
    }, [props.state])
    
  }
  return <Sound ref={sound} />
}

export default function PlayAmbientSound() {
  const [audioState, setAudioState] = useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <AmbientSound state={audioState} />
      <AudioButton state={audioState} onClick={() => setAudioState(!audioState)} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failed prop type errors are due to not passing the correct props to the `Sound` component.

If you take a look at [the README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound), you can see that the values you are assigning to `ref.current` can be passed as props to the component:

```
// In your React component:
render() {
  return (
    <Sound
      url="cool_sound.mp3"
      playStatus={Sound.status.PLAYING}
      playFromPosition={300 /* in milliseconds */}
      onLoading={this.handleSongLoading}
      onPlaying={this.handleSongPlaying}
      onFinishedPlaying={this.handleSongFinishedPlaying}
    />
  );
}
```

If you pass the values as props instead of assigning them to the ref, you should see those warnings go away. Here is the full list of props you can pass to `<Sound />`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound#props

Answer (score 0):

According to pat's solution I changed the code to this:

```
function AmbientSound(props) {
  let state = ''
  if(props.state){
      state = Sound.status.PLAYING
  }else{
      state = Sound.status.PAUSED
  }
  return (
    <Sound
      url='/sounds/ambientStereoSound.wav'
      autoLoad={true}
      playStatus={state}
      loop={true}
      volume={100}
    />
  )
}
```